# Golang template: what is in the context?

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to see what is in the context that is passed into the template.
What I do is basically putting the dot right there in the HTML.:

`{{$.}}`

What I get back when the HTML is rendered is:

`{http://localhost:1315/blog/index.xml 0xc08fdf36g0 map[Pages:[]] Blog [] map[] 2016-04-07 15:34:03 -0700 PDT 2016-04-07 15:34:03 -0700 PDT { 0} {/blog/ http://localhost:1315/blog/ } false 0xc0825878d0 {{0 0} 1} <nil>}`

I know for example there is `.Site` inside `.` but it doesn't even show up in the rendered HTML. How can I get the context in a more understandable form so I can see what it is without previously knowing all the attributes it is supposed to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{{ printf "%#v" . }}
```

Should print out the variable name and value.